# Invalid %%A auto parser

Tags: r

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with this command in R?

I literally have tried everything:

```
d0 <- "domingo 04 febrero 2018"

parse_date(d0, "%A %d %B %Y", locale = locale("es"))
```

When I execute the above code, I get an error that says

> "invalid %%A auto parser"

Comment: which package are you using?

Comment: Just the tidyverse. I am really new at this. Maybe there is an extra package I need.

Comment: It is limitation of `parse_date` function. You can use `as.POSIXct` function instead. I have added an answer with detailed description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%A` is a valid format per `ISO8601` specification.

The actual problem is that `parse_date` (a function from `readr` package) doesnot provide support for all of `ISO8601` specifications. Missing features include `Week` and `Weekday` specifications.

But we have an alternate solution in `base r` itself. Let me provide you few examples:

```
# %A is supported is base r
> as.character(Sys.Date(), "%A %d %B %Y")
[1] "Sunday 04 February 2018"

# Try to parse character string to date now
> as.POSIXct("Sunday 04 February 2018", format = "%A %d %B %Y")
[1] "2018-02-04 GMT"

# Lets execute the same code (converted to English) from OP
d0 <- "Sunday 04 February 2018"
as.POSIXct(d0, format = "%A %d %B %Y", tz = "GMT")

# Result :
[1] "2018-02-04 GMT"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was very useful

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem is that the "%A" format specification is not defined in the parse_date function.

```
d0 <- "04 febrero 2018"
parse_date(d0, "%d %B %Y", locale = locale("es"))
[1] "2018-02-04"
```

Comment: `%A` is a valid format per specification. The details available under help for `strptime` but this format is not supported by `parse_date` function. It has been documented as part of limitations of `parse_date` as well.